# Is there a way not to store the password when logging into Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I am trying U1 on android and I don't want to store my password on the device.

It would be nice (for me) to have the option to be asked for the password at login.

This is also required for the others platform clients.

Is there a way to force a password on logon?

Comment: Clear the data, each time

Answer (score 1):

The approach to this is fairly standard: most phones are single-user devices and I think it's widely expected that users only have one single-sign-on account. Logic follows that people will only need to sign in once.

But as Uri says, it can be done: you just need to clear the application data (through settings → applications).

If you need something more fluent than this, you'll want to file a bug against Ubuntu One. I suggest you explain *why* you need to do this because it's not the expected behaviour.